# Sending command line arguments to an already running python.exe

Tags: python, command-line, arguments

Python 3.10 64-bit (OS Windows10)

Hi,

with autopytoexe.exe (python) I compiled a test55.exe - I want to use it to control
the brightness of my usb camera. The camera brightness must be set to
"-7" during the day and at night the brightness must be set to "-1".

On sunrise my VB6 program (that is also self-written) outputs the command line:

```
test55.exe -7 (=camera exposure: normal sensitivity)
and on sunset the program outputs :
test55.exe -1 (=camera exposure: maximum sensitivity)
```

But each time when test55.exe is called there's a new Instance of
the program. I want only one instance of the test55.exe program.
-Is this possible to have only one instance of the program with the command line method?

If possible i don't want to use a webserver for that. Here is the
code (annotation: I omitted the python code for the brightness adjustment):

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk()
#root.title=("test")
text1=tk.Text(root, height=12, width=50)
text1.insert(tk.INSERT,"brightness,\r\n")
if len(sys.argv)==2:
    text1.insert(tk.INSERT,sys.argv[1])
else:
    text1.insert(tk.INSERT,"command line parameter: none")
text1.config(state="disabled")
text1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```